# Using casecmp in Ruby with Pattern Matching

Tags: ruby, string, pattern-matching

Is there any way to use casecmp in Ruby in conjunction with pattern matching?  For example, if I want to compare "Ba" with "Alabama", would I be able to do it with casecmp?

Thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean

```
"Alabama" =~ /Ba/i #=> 3
```

?

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html, section Options